# ValueError: No PKG-INFO in archive

Tags: python, pip, pypi, twine

I've been trying to upload my package to PyPI by taking these steps:

1. Registering on PyPI
2. Creating a hidden `.pypirc` file in my home directory (~/) containing:

   ```
   [distutils]
   index-servers = pypi

   [pypi]
   repository=https://pypi.python.org/pypi
   username=my_username
   password=my_password
   ```
3. Creating `LICENSE.TXT`, `requirements.txt`, and `setup.cfg` inside my package which contained this:

   ```
   [metadata]

   description-file = README.md
   ```
4. Creating `setup.py` inside my package containing this:

   ```
   from setuptools import setup
   setup(
     name='Package_name',
     packages=['Package_name'],
     version='1.0',
     description='Description,
     author= 'ShellRox',
     author_email='Email',
     url='Github url',
     download_url='Github download url',
     keywords=['authentication', 'steam', 'simple'],
     classifiers=[],
   )
   ```
5. Converting my package directory to `tar.gz` file:

```
tar -czvf Package_name.tar.gz Package_name
```

6. And finally, executing this command:

```
twine upload package_name.tar.gz
```

From which, I received this error:

> ValueError: No PKG-INFO in archive: PATH_HERE

---

I know that similar question has been asked before, But as you see i have already practiced solution question's only answer provided, But it didn't seem to work.

How should I put `PKG-INFO` in my archive? Could there be some problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a source distribution you need (instead of `tar`):

```
python setup.py sdist
```

Verify it before uploading — you may need to adjust `MANIFEST` or [MANIFEST.in](https://docs.python.org/3.4/distutils/sourcedist.html#specifying-the-files-to-distribute) to include everything.

To create binary packages:

```
python setup.py bdist_egg
```

and/or

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

Then `twine upload dist/*`.

Read [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/distutils/index.html) and [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/).

Comment: Sorry for late response and Thanks, it worked almost perfectly until it gave `HTTPError: 410 Client Error: Gone` error. But current problem is solved and i guess seperate problem has been displayed. Thank you again.